# how to create an agent can choose road to driving in anylogic?

Tags: java, simulation, agent, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

i create a supply chain model in anylogic
that have a distributor and 8 trailer and 5 trucks for Transport Order from distributor to retailers.

now anylogic routing are Automatic but i want to write the agents(trucks) that They can choose their own road.
what should I do?
grateful

Comment: Do you use the road traffic library or a GIS map? Please be more specific, add screenshots, etc. Also, what research have you done yourself already? cheers

Comment: yea 
i use GIS map
i want to trucks can decide choose road
now routing is automatic in anylogic

Answer (score 2):

In order to move an agent along the given route, you need to create a Route Provider by code and set it as route provider for the agent. 
The code sample can be found in the following example model: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5w2bw6cn9l8ez8/DynamicRoutes.alp?dl=0

You can specify any route drawn on the GIS map as argument of the function "getCustomRouteProvider()".

One important comment to the example model: when the initial location or target for an agent is defined as GIS Point of a network, the agent uses the shortest (fastest) route of the network to reach the destination. 
In order the agent follows the route specified while creating the custom route provider instead of, the agent is initially placed in the point defined by the latitude and longitude of the "gisPointStart" and moved to the point with coordinates (gisPointEnd.getLatitude(), gisPointEnd.getLongitude()).

Answer (score 0):

Using the GIS map, you can only make trucks use specific roads by defining separate waypoints (=GIS points) that force your trucks to use route A or B.

Comment: ok
thanks
But I have to decide trucks
How can I?
By writing Java code؟ Can you suggest me a resource?
thanks for your response